# onLoad set 10 ( or more) button.text from a txt file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a simple form with 10 or more buttons.
These are named Button1, Button2 etc.
I want the user to save a simple txt file for each button text in a folder. Why? Well Each end user will want to have different names for each button from the next user who will use the form. Each user will need to set his own text description to suit his needs. (once at set up) So in a folder location I have... Button1.txt, Button2.txt etc each with a default starting text.
On loading the form, I want to loop through the txt files and add the user edited names to each of the buttons.

I can get this to work long hand...doing it one at a time, 
but I know I should be able to loop through simply...

I have tried several variations on this

```
For i = 1 To 10
  Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\QuickButtons\ButtonTxt\Button" & i & ".txt"
  If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
  Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
  Me.Controls("Button" & i).Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
  objReader.Close()
Next
```

I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

For someone out there this is an easy one... if I had hair, I would be pulling it out! 
So I send you many thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this line `If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then` be `If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) == True Then`?

Comment: Thanks for quick start of the block... It didn't like the == so not sure? and I noticed I forgot the "end if" from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
Me.Controls("Button" & i).Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
```

This will only succeed if the buttons are contained **directly** by the Form.  If they are in a different container, like a Panel, then it would fail.

One solution is to search for the control like this:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\QuickButtons\ButtonTxt\Button" & i & ".txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
            Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)
            If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Button Then
                Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(matches(0), Button)
                btn.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FILE_NAME)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: OK, so maybe sending kisses would be too much ? That obviously was the bit of information I forgot to mention, that I had added tabs, and split the buttons over several tabs... It worked instantly, and maybe you all heard me shout "YES" ? Thanks again.... Instead of kisses I will just pass on the your praises...Many thanks Barry

Comment: @UncleWiggy: The best way to reward an SO member is to accept and/or upvote their answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to have a single XML file, where you would have all of your custom labels. Something like this:

```
<labels>
  <button index="0" name="button1" />
  <button index="1" name="button2" />
  ...
</labels>
```

Depending on your design, this may be inside your `app.config`, or a standalone file.